# how to remove two lines above after we find a match in a file in BASH?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that contain data like:

1. 123
2. 456
3. 789

I want to delete the above two lines (123 and 456) when I find a match 789. Is it possible to do it with sed or awk? Please Help

Comment: Does your file contain 1., 2. etc. also?

Comment: what about several match (delete form start unitl last match or only 2 previous line of the match ? what if match is on first or second line ?

Comment: yes my file contains serial numbers

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I just want to delete 2 previous lines after a match and the match must be at the last line.

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" is always "yes" so don't even ask that. Edit your question to show some more truly representative sample input and expected output. With what you've posted so far a solution that does `> file` would produce the apparently desired effect.

Comment: I see that you are a new user to SO. There are many answers to your question, so if you feel that one of them is sufficient, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry For the late reply. I really thank you for your help in a short time. I have got more than one good answers from below. I really appreciate your help.. thank You very much.

Comment: @Ed Morton Sorry for asking "is it possible". I tried a lot of web pages to get this answer, but unfortunately I was not able to find this. That is why I asked like that. Sorry for asking like that and Thank You very much to all for giving these nice and good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ed`, the standard editor:

```
ed -s file <<< $'3,$g/789/-2,.d\nw'
```

`ed` will see these commands:

```
3,$g/789/-2,.d
w
```

Explanation:

```
3,$g/789/
```

will mark all lines from line 3<sup>*</sup> to the end of the file that match `/789/`; then, for each marked line, it will execute the command:

```
-2,.d
```

which means: delete the range `-2,.`, i.e., the range that starts two lines above the current one (`-2`) and ends here (`.`).

Then `w` means to write the file. If you want to try it first without writing to the file, but instead print on the terminal (for testing purposes), replace the `w` command by `,p` and `Q` as so:

```
ed -s file <<< $'3,$g/789/-2,.d\n,p\nQ'
```

Note. `ed` really edits the file (it's an editor), so it will happily preserve symlinks and permissions, unlike all other methods that rely on tools that are good for streams (`sed` and `awk`).

Note. If your pattern appears in the first two lines, it will be preserved (though, this can be handled by adding some extra commands); if your pattern appears within a range of 2 lines, you might have some surprises, e.g.,

```
000
123
456
789
123
789
```

will yield an empty file, and

```
123
456
789
123
789
```

you'll get an error.

---

<sup>*</sup>The range starts at line 3, just to prevent errors in case your pattern appears in the first two lines

Comment: Good answer! :) The possibility to do a `-2` is great. I also played around with ed a while ago, but (as far as I remember) I ended up with the feeling that I don't like the fact that I need to pass the program to stdin.. But this answer shows a nice use case for `ed`.

Answer (score 1):

This script does not load the whole file into memory, unlike some of the other answers, so it's efficient for big files, and this assumes that you have at least 3 lines

```
#n
1{
    N
    h
    n
    :loop
    ${      
        /789/! {
               x
               p
               g                   
        }
        p
    }
    $!{
        H
        g
        P
        s/^[^\n]*\n//
        h
        n
        b loop
    }
}
```

If you save this as s.sed, you can run

```
sed -f s.sed file
```

And it will delete the two lines before the last line if the last line matches 789.

Input:

```
123
456
789
```

Output:

```
789
```

Input:

```
abc
123
456
789
```

Output:

```
abc
789
```

Input:

```
123
456
abc
```

Output:

```
123
456
abc
```

**Explanation**

The `#n` suppresses normal output. On the first line, matched by `1`, we append the next line with `N` and copy this to the hold space with `h`. Then we go to the next line with `n` and then start the `:loop`.

If the current line is the last line, which is picked up by `$`, then we check if it doesn't match 789, in which case we swap the pattern and hold spaces with `x`, print out the new pattern space with `p`, then use `g` to copy the hold space onto the pattern space. Finally we print out the last line.

If the current line isn't the last line. We append the current line to the hold space with `H`, then we copy the hold space to pattern space. We print the first line of the pattern space with `P`, and then remove the first line with `s/^[^\n]*\n//`. We copy this back to the hold space, go to the next line, and repeat the loop with `b loop`.

Comment: I basically like `sed` answers, but I think `sed` is not the right tool for this since it is very limited in case of flexibility here. What if the OP wants to remove 20 lines above the pattern? If you ask me, use awk and buffer those n lines which should get removed. This would also not require to have the whole file in memory, but it offers the flexibility to specify `n_lines_to_remove` like you wish. I mean this is what `awk` is meant for.

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) if(a[i+1] a[i+2]!~/789/) print a[i]}' test.1
```

> input (test.1)

```
1. 123
2. 456
3. 789
4. 012
5. 345
6. 678
7. 901
8. 789
9. 111
```

> output

```
3. 789
4. 012
5. 345
8. 789
9. 111
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/&/2;Ta;/\n789$/s/.*\n//;P;D' file
```

Keep a moving window of 3 lines in the pattern space and if the third line is the desired pattern, remove the first two lines.

Answer (score 0):

loading the file in memory (so not the best for huge file)

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d
     x;/\n[0-9]\{1,\}\.[[:space:]]\{1,\}789$/ s/\(\(\n\)[[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]]*\)\{3\}$/\2789/
    ' YourFile
```

load the file in memory, check if last line match, if yes remove 2 previous line, print result

Comment: This prints all lines for me.

Comment: which version of sed (this is a posix version so GNU sed need `--posix`)

Comment: `GNU sed version 4.1.5` Tried with `--posix` and still get all the lines ?

Comment: you are right, i test without the serial number before, added this in code

Comment: FYI the accepted `ed` answer also loads the whole file in memory.